# Is it possible to export a custom javascript object in different formats like the Date object can?

Tags: javascript, oop, object

For example, let's say I have a custom object like this:

```
function MyObject(a, b){
    this.prop = a;
    this.name = b;
    this.doSomething = function(){
        return "something";
    }
}
var a = new MyObject(4, 'name');
```

I want to be able to export this object as a string, or an integer, or whatever format the function calling it would warrant automatically in a similar way to how the Date object behaves, ie:

```
console.log(b);
// "name"
console.log(2*a);
// 8
console.log(a.doSomething());
// "something"
```

I have tried using:

```
MyObject.prototype.toString = function(){ ... }
```

But it doesn't seem to be what I'm looking for as I still have to call "a.toString()"

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer changes depending on whether you use ES5 and earlier, or ES2015 and later.

#### In ES2015 and later

**Yes**, you can implement the `Symbol.toPrimitive` method on your prototype and use the hint that it receives as its first argument:

```js
// (There's a more thoroughly ES2015+ version below, keeping
// this fairly ES5-like for comparison with the ES5 version)
function MyObject(num, name) {
  this.num = num;
  this.name = name;
}
MyObject.prototype[Symbol.toPrimitive] = function(hint) {
  return hint === "number" ? this.num : this.name;
};

var a = new MyObject(21, "half the answer");
console.log(a * 2);                       // 42
console.log("It says it's " + a);         // It says it's half the answer
```

I'm fairly certain this won't work on a truly ES5 JavaScript engine even with transpiling...

Note that I kept the code above fairly ES5-like so it's easy to compare with the example under ES5 earlier. But in ES2015 we'd probably write it like this:

```js
class MyObject {
  constructor(num, name) {
    this.num = num;
    this.name = name;
  }
  [Symbol.toPrimitive](hint) {
    return hint === "number" ? this.num : this.name;
  }
}

let a = new MyObject(21, "half the answer");
console.log(a * 2);               // 42
console.log("It says it's " + a); // It says it's half the answer
```

#### In ES5 and earlier

You can't have quite as much control as JavaScript itself does, where it uses the "hint" on the abstract [`ToPrimitive`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-toprimitive) operation to choose `valueOf` or `toString` in a special way for `Date`.

But you can get close by implementing `valueOf` and `toString`. When your object is coerced to a number, `valueOf` will be used. When coerced to string, `toString` will be used.

**But**, note that `+` will use `valueOf` even if the other operand is a string:

Example:

```js
function MyObject(num, name) {
  this.num = num;
  this.name = name;
}
MyObject.prototype.valueOf = function() {
  return this.num;
};
MyObject.prototype.toString = function() {
  return this.name;
};

var a = new MyObject(21, "half the answer");
console.log(a * 2);                       // 42
console.log("It says it's " + a);         // It says it's 21
console.log("It says it's " + String(a)); // It says it's half the answer
```

If you didn't implement `valueOf`, through the somewhat convoluted processing that's done, it would end up using `toString` even in the `+` case (see the `ToPrimitive` link above for the gory details; basically, eventually it does OrdinaryToPrimitive and calls `Object.prototype.valueOf`, which returns an object, and so it disregards that and uses `toString` instead).

Comment: ...and when stringifyied for JSON, `toJSON` will be called. :)

Comment: Worth noting that if there is no `valueOf` implementation, it would use `toString()` for string concatenation.

Comment: Is there then any way to avoid having to use: "String(a)"? For example, for the Date method, if I were to log it to the console, it would give me a date string and would only be coerced to an integer if I wrote something like console.log(1*d);

Comment: @MadaraUchiha: Yes, true, through fairly convoluted logic. I've added a note at the end.

Comment: @renegadeds: You can in ES2015 and later. You can't in ES5 and earlier. I've added ES2015 to the answer.

Comment: @renegadeds: Thank *you*, the question reminded me of `Symbol.toPrimitive`, which I'd somehow forgotten. I can only apologise for the ES5-only original answer. :-)